# finnhub installation using pip

Tags: python, pip, finnhub

I've currently installation of python 3.10 [not conda dist]. I'm trying to import finnhub using both cmd but I'm confronted with the following error message:

```
C:\Users\Admin>python -m pip install finnhub
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement finnhub (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for finnhub
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing please? I've also tried to install this package using PyCharm but this results in the following error:

```
C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\NewPython\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/NewPython/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\NewPython\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import finnhub
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'finnhub'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have added the python installation to PATH and the current version of pip is the latest version.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

**Question update**
In the meantime, I have spotted an old environment reference which has been now removed. This seems to allow the install of finnhub using

```
pip install finnhub--python
```

but not

```
pip install finnhub
```

Code below:

```
C:\Users\Admin>pip install finnhub
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement finnhub (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for finnhub

C:\Users\Admin>pip install finnhub--python
Requirement already satisfied: finnhub--python in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (2.4.13)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.22.0 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from finnhub--python) (2.28.1)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.22.0->finnhub--python) (1.26.10)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.22.0->finnhub--python) (2022.6.15)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.22.0->finnhub--python) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3,>=2 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.22.0->finnhub--python) (2.1.0)

C:\Users\Admin>
```

When using PyCharm to try to access this from the IDE, I am now confronted with:

```
C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import finnhub
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'finnhub'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: did you try `python -m pip install finnhub-python`?

Comment: Hi @Sala,, yes I did actually - with the same error response as mentioned in my comment to the eloquent and helpful @ Melanol.  I also made sure that all references to prior Python installs were removed from my environment variables.

Comment: Could you please try to do the following: 
- Open a python console and check it works (import numpy for example)
- Try to install another package (ex. pip install tqdm) and tell me if it works

Comment: Yes, the "pip install tqdm" code works.In the meantime, I removed an old path environment variable, which seems to allow pip to install the package using --python suffix. To clarify, I have amended my original comment to provide further info.

Answer (score 1):

From the the section "Installation" of the package's documentation:

```
pip install finnhub-python
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I've already tried this with the following error: C:\Users\Admin>pip install finnhub-python
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python34\python.exe"  "c:\python34\scripts\pip.exe" install finnhub-python'

Answer (score 0):

In this command, it becomes clear that you have installed `finhub` globally,

```
C:\Users\Admin>pip install finnhub--python
Requirement already satisfied: finnhub--python in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (2.4.13)
```

But when running your script your command looks like this

```
C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\NewPython\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/NewPython/main.py
```

So you are using a virtual environment for your project in which finnhub is probably not installed yet.

Try:

```
C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\NewPython\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install finnhub-python
```

Alternatively, you can use pycharm as well

1. With your project open go to **File**
2. Select **Settings**->**Project**->**Python Interpreter**
3. You should see a list of packages and their version. Hit the little **+** button above it
4. Search for `finnhub-python`, select it and hit *Install Package*